# Wrap text inside expanded FlexibleSpaceBar

Tags: flutter, dart, frontend, flutter-layout

I have some screens with a FlexibleSpaceBar to show big text, that scales down when scrolling downward. How can I wrap the text when the FlexibleSpaceBar is in the expanded state?

**Video of the problem:**
[Le video](https://i.imgur.com/1su9qMq.mp4)

**Relevant code**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class SelectPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Widget child;

  const SelectPage({Key key, @required this.title, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              brightness: Brightness.light,
              iconTheme: Theme.of(context).iconTheme,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                title: Text(
                  title,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.color),
                  maxLines: 10,
                  softWrap: true,

                ),
                centerTitle: true,
              ),
              expandedHeight: 200,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              floating: true,
            ),
            this.child
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to copy *FlexibleSpaceBar* and modify its build function a bit. 
By default, FlexibleSpaceBar uses scale transform to animate title's size:

```dart
        children.add(Container(
          padding: padding,
          // Here comes scale transform
          child: Transform(
            alignment: titleAlignment,
            transform: scaleTransform,
            child: Align(
              alignment: titleAlignment,
              child: DefaultTextStyle(
                style: titleStyle,
                child: title,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

I suggest removing whole *Transform* widget. Instead, take *scaleValue* variable and use it in *titleStyle* like this:

```dart
        final double scaleValue = Tween<double>(begin: 1.5, end: 1.0).transform(t);
        TextStyle titleStyle = theme.primaryTextTheme.title;
        titleStyle = titleStyle.copyWith(
          color: titleStyle.color.withOpacity(opacity),
          fontSize: titleStyle.fontSize * scaleValue
        );
```

And don't set *fontSize* in title's Text widget. Set it in *ThemeData.primaryTextTheme.title* or straight in modified FlexibleSpaceBar.

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

 I did what you described; https://pastebin.com/k2C6dpTv

But now it won't scale at all. The size of the text remains the same whilst scrolling. Did I miss something?

Comment: @g3mini Did you remove *fontSize: 20* from *title* widget? Please do, if you haven't done this.

Comment: I have done that =)

```
title: Text(
                  title,
                  style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.title,
                )
```

Comment: @g3mini Sorry, I can't see where the problem is. Take a look at my complete code, maybe you'll see the difference: https://pastebin.com/a2TnUKwH

Comment: I found it, you're a legend! 

                  style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.color)

Is what got me.

Thank you very much!